# Efficient way to create Lua threads?

Tags: lua

a quick question regarding threading in Lua via c++ game engine...

I am wondering about the efficiency of creating Lua threads. It doesn't look like something we want to be doing a lot as it seems that each time a thread is creating there is a big copy of the Lua chunk. So -

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);

lua_State *thread = lua_newthread(L);
luaL_loadfile(thread, "luac1.bin"); // or luaL_loadbuffer or ?
lua_resume(thread, NULL, 0);
```

The new thread always involves the copying of the chunk data, and when the thread ends the chunk is lost I believe. Is there an efficient way to be able to spawn these threads over and over without any chunk copy each time?

[edit] I should add that these are threads as they will likely want to Yield before they end.

thanks

Comment: I find it odd that you properly say "Lua" in the title, but then go on to butcher it and say "LUA" in the post.

Comment: What's the purpose of that "threading"? Lua threads is not something that work in parallel, it's for coroutines. If you need something that runs long and yields often, then Lua threads is ok. If you just need script executed on some event, then you don't need Lua threads.

Comment: @Vlad yes, those threads will yield often. But say I had a lot of game objects coming in and out of existence. I'd like each one to run a yielding Lua thread, but I don't want to be copying that chunk data each time I'm spawning a new thread...

Comment: @warspyking well, rejoice then, for the crime is edited

Comment: You don't have to reload script on every new thread created. Let that chunk be a class, or set of functions, loaded just once at the game start. New per-object thread will then call existing function to handle object's state. State itself doesn't need loading, it is created and initialized with calls to already loaded functions.

Comment: There are no lua threads... just coroutines. And I don't think lua is thread safe. I use coroutines with state machines, to simulate true multithreading on my scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `lua_xmove`: "Exchange values between different threads of the same state."

```d
lua_State* L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);

lua_State* thread1 = lua_newthread(L);
lua_State* thread2 = lua_newthread(L);

// load chunk as a function and copy it to the top of each thread's stack
luaL_loadfile(L, "luac1.bin");
lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
lua_xmove(L, thread1, 1);
lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
lua_xmove(L, thread2, 1);

lua_resume(thread1, NULL, 0);
lua_resume(thread2, NULL, 0);
```

This way you only have to load the chunk once. the threads are all sharing the same instance.